How to avoid PayPal 'PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID' error?
I'm trying to make an application to buy games online. And I'm currently working on the payment page. I've implemented a PayPal to PayPal transactions successfully and now I'm working on to make a Credit Card to PayPal transactions.
So I've made a front end page with all the inputs that I've needed: Card Number, Expiration Date and CVV. And I want that when I press on the buy button, the client send the card number, expiration date and cvv to an express API. Then when in the API, I make the payment such like the PayPal to PayPal method that I've used.
Here is my client-side code :
const CreditCardNumber = document.getElementById("CreditCardNumber");
const CreditCardCVV = document.getElementById("CreditCardCVV");
const ExpireMonth = document.getElementById("ExpireMonth");
const ExpireYear = document.getElementById("ExpireYear");

fetch(properties.api + '/getProductByInvoiceToken',{
    method:'POST',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://127.0.0.1:5500'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'number' : CreditCardNumber.value,
         'cvv2' : CreditCardCVV.value,
         'expireMonth' : ExpireMonth.options[ExpireMonth.selectedIndex].value,
         'expireYear' : ExpireYear.options[ExpireYear.selectedIndex].value,
    })
})

Here is my server-side code :
app.post('/buyWithCreditCard',(req,res)=>{
    const { number, expireMonth, expireYear, cvv } = req.body;
    paypal.payment.create({
        intent: 'sale',
        payer: {
            payment_method: 'credit_card',
            funding_instruments: [{
                credit_card: {
                    number: number,
                    type: 'visa',
                    expire_month: expireMonth,
                    expire_year: expireYear,
                    cvv2: cvv2,
                    first_name: "John",
                    last_name: "Doe"
                }
            }]
        },
        transactions: [{
            amount: {
                total: product.child('Price').val(),
                currency: "USD"
            },
            description: 'Payment desc.'
        }]
    }, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
        } else {
            console.log('LTETT');
        }
    });
});

Every time I'm trying to pay, the app throws the following error:
{
    name: 'PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID', 
    message: 'Payee account is invalid.', 
    information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#error-PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID', debug_id: 'cd64907fda648', 
httpStatusCode: 400
}

Can someone please help with this?
I'm excepting the server to respond correctly

Using the v1/payments API for credit card processing was deprecated a very long time ago. Your account is not (and will not be) set up to receive such payments, therefore it is invalid, hence the error message.
See the current Standard and Advanced integration guides.
